# Javascript: converting from military to standard time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert this military time clock to standard time. I am NEW (just learning) how to code computers and have no idea what to do. Websites, resources, ideas would be much appreciated. 
Thank you!

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <head>
   <title>Digital Clock</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    // this function actually updates the clock display. It will be called
    // every second provided by the setInterval() call in the document body
    function updateClock()
  {
  var time = new Date();              // create a new time stamp
  var hours = time.getHours();        // retrieve hours from the time stamp
  hours = format(hours);              // ... and format them

  var minutes = time.getMinutes();    // retrieve minutes from the time stamp
  minutes = format(minutes);          // ... and format them

  var seconds = time.getSeconds();    // retrieve seconds from the time stamp
  seconds = format(seconds);          // ... and format them

  // update the text field (the top clock)
  document.clock.display.value = hours + ":" + minutes + ":"
  + seconds;                  

  // update the button text (the bottom clock)
  document.clock.display2.value = hours + ":" + minutes; 
  }

 // this function adds a leading zero to the number if it is below 10
 function format(number)
 {
 if (number < 10)
 {
 number = "0" + number;
 }
  return number; 
  }
 //   -->
</script>
 </head>

 <body bgcolor="lightyellow">
 <h2>Digital Clock</h2>

 <form name="clock" action="#">
 <p><input type="text" size="8" name="display" value="12:00:00" /></p>
 <p><input type="button" name="display2" value="12:00:00" /></p>
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval("updateClock()", 1000);   // update the clocks every second
</script>

<p>More information on the digital clock design can be found 
<a href="time.html">here</a>.</p>

<p>You can examine the code of the project by clicking on <b>"View" -&gt;
"Source"</b> buttons in Internet Explorer.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, keep learning , google search is good, example "javascript convert military time", w3school (w3fool posters shhh).  There is lots of places to learn.  I'd try the google search first and the basics of javascript, as this is less physical resources needed

Comment: I should add that on this site you need to ask some more specific questions and appear to have done your search for an answer first before asking but since your "new" I thought I'd help rather than down vote

Answer (score 0):

After the line:

```
  hours = format(hours);
```

You should be able to use something such as:

```
if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
}
```